# Using coroutineScope function vs passing CoroutineScope as argument

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine, coroutinescope, structured-concurrency

Using **coroutineScope** in a **suspend** function that will be called from a **CoroutineScope**, is it giving the same result as passing that **CoroutineScope** as a parameter to the **suspend** function ?

```kotlin
import kotlinx.coroutines.coroutineScope

suspend fun loadContributorsConcurrent() {
    coroutineScope {
        // launch...
    }
}
```

```kotlin
suspend fun loadContributorsConcurrent(outerScope: CoroutineScope) {
    outerScope.run {
        // launch...
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should you pass coroutineScope as function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61606630/should-you-pass-coroutinescope-as-function-argument)

Comment: No, in the first, coroutines launched from within are children and it will wait for them. In the second, the launched coroutines will be siblings and will not be waited for.

Comment: @tornadoradon Not really, I saw that question before posting mine, I'm not really asking about the difference between passing a **CoroutineScope** as argument or creating an **extension function** for it. I want to know the difference between passing **CoroutineScope** as an argument or creating a new nested one with `coroutineScope` function

Answer (score 0):

No.  In the second version, you can pass a scope that does not match the scope in which `loadContributorsConcurrent` is actually run.  The use of `run` makes things even worse, as code will usually be run in the correct scope *except* launch or async coroutines.

The first pattern is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

The code in your second proposal has a major flaw, it does not suspend. Meaning that if you were to launch on the injected scope, it would launch an asynchronous job.

I have not yet seen a use-case for injecting the scope, I'd opt for a suspending function, in your case the first option.